# contract.getaddress returns undefined

Tags: hardhat

I am deploying a contract that I then want to use its address as a constructor in another contract to be deployed.

Here is my code but getaddress returns undefined

'''

```
const contractname = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Contractname");
await contractname.waitForDeployment();
console.log(contractname.getaddress);
```

'''

Comment: try `contractname.target`

Comment: contractname.address

Comment: in etherjs6 "await contractname.getAddress()"